# How should I set up a search widget that customers can embed on their sites?

Tags: php, forms, codeigniter, search, cross-domain

My company crawls the websites of companies in our system and allows users to search those companies specifically.  We currently use Sphinx for all our search tools.

Our customers ( the companies we index ) are asking for a search widget that they can embed on their sites to add search functionality to their own websites. The search widget will allow a user to submit a search query from our customer's website. The results will then load on our site ( this search functionality is already working on our site ... just not the embeddable widget ). At first this seemed simple, but then I started thinking about security and cross domain form submissions.

The search functionality already exists on our site at a uri like this:
`/companies/profile_search/1581/die-cutting`

`companies` is my controller. `profile_search` is my method. `1581` is the id of the company to be searched. `die-cutting` is the search query.

I'd like our customers to be able to simply cut and paste code into their site to embed the widget.

1. Should I simply direct the search query to the above url?
2. If no, how should I set this up so that it's secure?
3. Are there other concerns I'm overlooking here?

Our site is built mostly in PHP using CodeIgniter and Sphinx for search, if that is helpful.

Comment: You could either do an `iframe` or `form` with a "branded" landing `action` pointing to your site when submitting (a la Google), or develop an AJAX REST service. Probably I would start on a unified search model that exposes search results at the site level and work "up" to global search, so you can focus on site perimeter security concerns and then abstract that up to a global federated search (possibly managing identity with a SSO server-side strategy like Shibboleth).

Comment: Maybe there's a wrinkle to this I'm not catching on to, but isn't the horse out of the gate security-wise if the federated search is already in place? Anyways, in the central search location, do you have a means to identify requests and any granularity of control over data access and permission? In other words, can you wall of certain parts of the site on a role basis? Or is it just opened up and free to search anything?

Comment: The company specific search feature is not live in production yet. Will probably be free to search anything, although we could put it behind an auth wall.  I suppose the horse is already out of the gate if it's open.

Comment: It's an interesting problem; how to give *enough* access while mitigating *inappropriate* access? You have to identify an authorization pattern to overlay if you have concerns about the data. A basic principle is [least privilege](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_privilege) with a [capability-based security model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capability-based_security). I suggest [ring modeling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ring_%28computer_security%29) and [role-based access control](http://csrc.nist.gov/groups/SNS/rbac/). If the concern warrants the resources to implement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CodeIgniter has built-in CSRF protection, which might get in your way if you ask your customers paste a `form` into their sites.

The easy way to do this would be to give your customers an `iframe` tag to paste in, and serve the `form` from your site, using `target="_top"` to make form submissions reload the whole window.

Comment: I agree, CSRF tokens are more complicated to manage than what most consider "drag and drop code". An `iframe` certainly seems the most reasonable approach.

Comment: Does CodeIgniter's CSRF stuff apply to GET requests??

Answer (score 0):

You could also simply disable CSRF for this method only; using either a pre-system hook or, more hackishly as a conditional in `config.php` such as:

```
 $config['csrf_protection'] = (stripos($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"],'/controller/method') === FALSE) ? TRUE : FALSE;
```

A detailed discussion on temporarily disabling CSRF can be found [here](http://codeigniter.com/forums/viewthread/182631/).

Answer (score 0):

For cross-domain requests you can use JSONP: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP